# Why do we need Jordan-Wigner transformation when simulating fermionic systems on quantum circuits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

Why do we need to do a Jordan-Wigner transformation when we want to simulate the fermionic systems with a quantum circuit model? I understand that the spin operator $\sigma_x, \sigma_y, \sigma_z$ on different sites commute with each other while fermion operators on different sites anticommute with each other.

However, can this transformation be avoided if we specify the basis we use beforehand? For example, consider a one dimensional quantum circuit consisting of N qubits (N being even) with i labeling the qubit (i starting from 0). We want to simulate the dynamics of a fermionic system on it.

The fermionic system we consider is a one dimensional chain of same size, with a two step Hamiltonian:

$H_1 = \sum_{i even} a_i^\dagger a_{i+1} + h.c. $ ,    $0<t<\frac{\pi}{2}$

$H_2 = \sum_{i odd} a_i^\dagger a_{i+1} + h.c.$, $\frac{\pi}{2} < t < \pi$

The hopping terms in each Hamiltonian is completely separable. We may naively interpret the first Hamiltonian as applying gates to the circuit on even bound while the second Hamiltonian as applying gates to the circuit on odd bound.

To be more precise, each bound consists two fermions (two qubits). If we label the fermionic states $|vac>, a_2^\dagger|vac>, a_1^\dagger|vac>, a_1^\dagger|vac>, a_1^\dagger a_2^\dagger |vac>$ as |00>, |01>,|10>,|11>, the unitary acting on the two fermions space could be written as
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&0&-i&0 \\
0&-i&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

which can be naively interpreted as a two qubit gate. And the two step Hamiltonian evolution can be interpreted as two layers of quantum circuits.

Here's my question: Since a lot of paper commented that to simulate a fermionic system you have to perform a Jordan-Wigner transformation, what is wrong with the naive interpretation above? The different terms in the Hamiltonian consists of quadratic terms thus separate terms commute with each other. What would go wrong if I try to directly simulate the fermionic system with such a mapping?

Edit: An argument is presented below

Consider a fermionic system consisting of N subsystems. We have N Hamiltonians that act on each of these subsystems and do not couple (commute with each other), i.e. $H = \sum_i H_i$.

Consider the unitary the total Hamiltonian generated: U = exp[-iHt]. We choose the basis as $a_{1a}^\dagger a_{1b}^\dagger ... a_{Na}^\dagger a_{Nb}^\dagger |vac>$ with the operators in smaller subsystems with smaller sites appearing first. The first subscript indicates the subsystem and the second subscript means different sites in one subsystem. The matrix element can be calculated as U$a_{1a}^\dagger ... a_{Nb}^\dagger |vac>$, (suppose U doesn't change the vacuum)which can be decomposed into:

$(e^{-iH_1t}a_{1a}^\dagger ..e^{iH_1t}) ... (e^{-iH_Nt}a_{Na}^\dagger ... e^{iH_Nt}) |vac>$

Each term in the bracket transform according to their separate unitary matrices, denoted by $U_{i_1j_1}^1$ for example. The transformation of the whole basis would be a tensorproduct of these separate matrices because the order of the operators are preserved. Thus at least for the first layer, this interpretation works fine.

Comment: Why do you think your proposal would work? If you give an argument, one could try to show where it fails.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I just added an argument under a special circumstance. It seems to me that my proposal works under this occasion.

Comment: Words like "careful ordering" don't belong into a rigorous argument.  What on earth does "careful" mean?  You have to be more formal.  Short answer: No, you can't do that -- except on 1D chains with nearest neighbor couplings and open boundary conditions, and even then, some care might be needed.  And the cases in which it works can straightforwardly be understood using the Jordan-Wigner transform :)

Comment: Without going into much details, one definitely needs a mapping from the fermionic system they want to simulate to what the quantum computer utilizes (e.g. qubits). In the case of standard quantum computation, Jordan-Wigner transformation takes care of this mapping. However, as far as I understand it's not the only possible mapping, specifically if you don't limit yourself to standard quantum computation models. E.g. see generalized Jordan-Wigner transformations by Batista and Ortiz and Fermionic Quantum computation by Bravyi and Kitaev.

Comment: I think the problem is that I only considered the simplest case with nearest interactions. The argument I presented would not work if the interactions work on systems not adjacent to each other. In 2d system with 'S' labeling this can not be avoided. Thanks for all the reply.